# Rewrite URL based on home_url

Tags: url-rewriting

The URL I am hitting is:

```
home_url('18/profile')
```

I want URL to be executed as:

```
localhost/wordpress/seller?page=profile
```

18 is the page ID for seller page.

Also, when I hit on above said URL multiple time then last part of URL appending continuously.

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );

// flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
function my_flush_rules(){
$rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

if ( ! isset( $rules['(wordpress)/(\d*)$'] ) ) {
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
}

// Adding a new rule
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{

$newrules = array();
$newrules['(wordpress)/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]';
return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{
array_push($vars, 'page');
return $vars;
}
```

Comment: Please [improve your question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). Summarize your specific problem, do not include the word WordPress. Also, format your code. :)

Comment: @VarunKumar Sure thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'insert_custom_rules');

add_filter('query_vars', 'insert_custom_vars');


function insert_custom_vars($vars){        

    $vars[] = 'main_page';       

    return $vars;

}

function insert_custom_rules($rules) {

    $newrules = array();

    $newrules=array(
        'page-name/(.+)/?' => 'index.php?pagename=page-name&main_page=$matches[1]'
    );

    return $newrules + $rules;
}
```

So, with the help of get_query_var() function, we can get value from url and use accordingly. In this way, we can get pretty URLs using Php.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to redirect:

```
http://example.com/18/profile
```

to

```
http://example.com/seller?page=profile
```

If so, add the following to your `.htaccess` file in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tags that were created by WordPress:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^18/profile/?$ seller?page=profile [R=301]
```

Your `.htaccess` should looks like the following if it hasn't been modified by another plugin:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Custom Rewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^18/profile/?$ seller?page=profile [R=301]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @Ethan Jinks O'Sullivan. But the problem is I don't want to do this using .htaccess. Is there any way to do this by adding rules using php, like the code mentioned in question.